# How do I disable a specific warning? "Sprite Tiling might not appear correctly because the Sprite used is not generated..:" I don't care about this

Tags: unity-game-engine

This error is flooding my console because all the objects I have are using the sliced draw mode.

```
Sprite Tiling might not appear correctly because the Sprite used is not generated with Full Rect. To fix this, change the Mesh Type in the Sprite's import setting to Full Rect
UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer:set_drawMode (UnityEngine.SpriteDrawMode)
```

I don't want to see this error as it doesn't concern me. How do I hide or stop it?

I have tried writing `#pragma warning disable` at the top of the script that changed the draw mode to sliced, I expected it to hide the warnings but it did not.
Also, it would be an inconvenience if all the warnings and errors from the script were to be hidden and not just this specific one.